# how to add explicit wait in drop down in selenium which is dependent on another Dropdown list?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, appium

how to add explicit wait in drop down using selenium until it finds the text ?
[image: UI]

[image: MY CODE]

Comment: no body was able to solve that problem .. so i am reposting it again

Comment: So you will keep on reposting it until someone solves it? :) This is not how this site works.

Comment: the previous question became too messy with some different answer

Comment: @Pope You should add more details instead of posting same question again! Share `HTML` and your `Java` code as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code will wait until specified text is not present..

```
    int i=0;

    while(i==0)
    {
        try{
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("ELEMENT_XPATH")));
            select.getOptions().indexOf(0);
            int ed = select.getOptions().indexOf(0);
            if(ed==0); //check whether it's got your index or not(if not then it will throw error and go to Catch section)
            {
                System.out.println("Pass got.. Index Value");
            }
            i=1; //if it got your index value in drop down then .. exit from loop..
        }catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException NSEE)
        {
            i=0; // iteration will continue until .. you'll not get your index in Drop down.. 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I HAVE TO WAIT on basis of index.. not as xpath

Comment: Okay.. you want to wait.. until drop down list's value is visible ?

Comment: yes.. correct.. as u see the 2nd drop down is invisible untill the 1st one complete fetching the entire list

Comment: For that you have to be sure .. which 'value' in 1st drop-down will load last.. or visible last.. (after that value visible in 1st DD.. 2nd drop-drop visibles).. do you know value ?

Comment: i want to wait by index or wait till 2nd dropdown list is availailble

Comment: Okay .. let me think ... I guess I know

Comment: Updated.. answer bro... hope this will work.. or will give you close idea.. to complete your task...